# mapping xaml columns to columns generated in code behind for wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to display a byte array with around 300 elements in a data grid containing 16 columns and the required number of rows. I am generating both columns and rows in the code behind for a data table and then binding the data table to the data grid item source. I need to change the header style of each column. How can i do this? In case I generate 16 columns in xaml then, how can i map these columns to the ones generated in the code behind file?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the DataGrid binding at code behind itself. But you should define the grid in the XAML and set auto generate columns set to false. Then, Define the `Window.Resources` and set style TargetType as DataGridColumnHeader. In this style you can modify the header appearance

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```